# Why does QAbstractItemModel::setData break the displayed text and fetched data() values?

Tags: qt

Let's populate a QComboBox from a QStringListModel

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QStringListModel>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QStringList data = QStringList () << "abc" << "def" << "ghi";

    auto model = new QStringListModel ();

    model -> setStringList (data);

    for (int i = 0; i < data .size (); ++i)
    {
        model -> setData (
            model -> index (i),
            Qt :: UserRole,
            i);

        qWarning ()
            << "setData(" << i << " -> " << model -> index (i)
            << ", " << i << ")";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data .size (); ++i)
    {
        qWarning ()
            << model -> index (i) << " :" 
            << model -> data (model -> index (i), Qt :: UserRole);
    }

    QComboBox box;
    box .setModel (model);
    box .show ();

    return app .exec ();
}
```

Output:

```
setData( 0  ->  QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,QStringListModel(0x1a993a0) )  ,  0 )
setData( 1  ->  QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,QStringListModel(0x1a993a0) )  ,  1 )
setData( 2  ->  QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,QStringListModel(0x1a993a0) )  ,  2 )
QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,QStringListModel(0x19a06b0) )   : QVariant(Invalid)
QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,QStringListModel(0x19a06b0) )   : QVariant(Invalid)
QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,QStringListModel(0x19a06b0) )   : QVariant(Invalid)
```

If I comment out the `setData` line, I get the expected entries "abc", "def", "ghi" in the combobox. If I leave it in, the entries day "256", "def", 256. Also, fetching the data from the indices clearly isn't working.

Come to think of it, why is 0x1a993a0 not the same as 0x19a06b0?
What's going on?

Qt 5.4 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QStringListModel::setData` works only for `Qt::EditRole` and `Qt::DisplayRole`.
From qt source:

```
bool QStringListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (index.row() >= 0 && index.row() < lst.size()
        && (role == Qt::EditRole || role == Qt::DisplayRole)) {
        lst.replace(index.row(), value.toString());
        emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And maybe you need to write

```
model->setData(model->index(i), i, Qt::UserRole);
```

enstead of

```
model->setData(model->index(i), Qt::UserRole, i);
```